# Whats wrong with symfony 2 route with parameter & name

Tags: routes, symfony

I have a symfony 2 route like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/thing/add/{id}", name="addThing")
 */
function addThing(Request $req) {
```

when I access `/thing/add/1`, symfony 2 complains:

> The "addThing" route has some missing mandatory parameters ("id").

But in the profiler, I see under "request attributes", "id" = 1. But theres nothing in GET (or POST). Whats the problem?

**UPDATE**

If I remove `name="addThing"` it works ... but how do I access that route for my form action?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but what happens when you add the parameter id to your addTrings-Method like this: `function addThing(Request $req, $id) {`? Does this work?

Comment: It appears to work now (even with the old code, I did try this & that, so I might have fixed something unknowingly). I'm not too sure why... anyone with ideas let me know :)

Comment: Perhaps the cache refreshed? Did you try a `php app/console cache:clear` when you were having the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just complete the answer provided by @scube.

First of all, you should not pass the `Request` object directly in the action function of your controller. The reason is that arguments in those kind of functions (functions used as action in a controller) are used solely for the purpose of mapping part of the url into arguments. For example, if I have an annotation like `@Route(/blog/{year}/{month}/{day)`, then, for arguments to being populated, you need an action function like this one:

```
public function blogViewAction($year, $month, $day) {
    // ...
}
```

This way, `$year` will be populated by the `year` argument from the url, `$month` by `month` and `$day` by `day`. The name of the variable in the url must match the name of your argument.

If you want to use the request object and you are in a controller, you request it from the dependency injection container like this:

```
$request = $this->get('request');
```

This is the way to define action in controller. Your definition of your route should look like this, same as @scube said:

```
/**
 * @Route("/thing/add/{id}", name="addThing")
 */
public function addThing($id) {
    // ...
}
```

Check that your route is registered in Symfony2 by running `php app/console router:debug`. This will print every routes known by the framework in your project. Check that the name `addThing` is there and the url mapping is good.

Finally, even if scope modifiers are not mandatory (`public`, `protected`, `private`) because `public` is the default, it is a good convention to always specify one.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: ic, I read in the [Symfony Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html), `public function updateAction(Request $request)`. Didn't know it was wrong

Comment: it was mentioned in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#book-controller-request-argument) that I could do that tho? Is the docs wrong? I thought the `@Route` annotation are used for mapping url to params?

Answer (score 0):

First: why the error message mention "addNote" and not "addThing"?
Second: In order to use the id value in your url you need to define your function like this:

```
function addThing($id) { ... }
```

Comment: Oh, I renamed the Note to Thing for the sake of posting the qn.